# What does 'pards' mean in Keats's 'Ode to a Nightingale'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry, nineteenth-century-english

John Keats's 'Ode to a Nightingale' contains the line "Not charioted by Bacchus and his pards,".

> Away! away! for I will fly to thee,
> Not charioted by Bacchus and his pards,
> But on the viewless wings of Poesy,
> Though the dull brain perplexes and retards

In this passage, it seems that 'pards' means 'pardners' (i.e., 'partners'). But if so, this is inconsistent with the assertion given by Merriam-Webster that the first use of 'pard' as a short form of 'pardner' is in the year 1850, because Keats died in 1821. So, what is the meaning of 'pards' in this poem?

Comment: https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/paintings/glossary/bacchus

Comment: I don’t know which version of M-W you are referencing, but this one has *pard* meaning *leopard* right at the top: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pard

Comment: @TimR well spotted.

Comment: @TinfoilHat You're right. It just wasn't on my radar that 'leopard' was, pun intended, in the running:)

Comment: English used to have [_pards_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pard) (panthers), [_leopards_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard) (lion panthers), and [_camelopards_](https://jakubmarian.com/origin-of-the-words-camelopard-and-giraffe/) (_camel panthers_, aka _giraffes_). To say nothing of [_ounces_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_leopard) (snow leopards). And then there is the more recently named North American genus of Pleistocene camels, [_camelops_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelops).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pard* [is <strike>short for</strike> leopard](https://www.google.com/search?q=pard%20define), a creature with which Bacchus (Dionysus) is sometimes associated. It's simple allusory detail, there only for rhyme, without any other significance within the greater context; Keats means that he needs no wine, just simple poetry, to understand the beauty of the Nightingale.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond Heartspring’s answer, I just wanted to add that “Leopard” is actually derived from a compound word, so etymologically, it wasn’t originally a shortening.

See Latin *[pardus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pardus#Latin)*.

(This doesn’t mean that it wasn’t viewed as a shortening by Keats’ time.)

Comment: It's a wiki, so you're welcome to edit and correct my answer. Up to you, I guess.

Comment: @Heartspring: I phrased it this way because I see it as an alternative perspective rather than a correction.